# Java's compareTo() function equivalent in Perl?

Tags: java, perl, function, compareto

What's the Perl function that achieves the same thing as `compareTo`() in Java? I know about `eq` and `ne` but I want to compare to see if one string is greater than another.

Comment: You'll get better answers to questions like this if you explain exactly what `compareTo` does in Java.  Not all Perl programmers know Java.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You actually have `cmp` (for strings) and `<=>` (for numbers) operators.
See [the Equality Operators section in perlop](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Equality-Operators).

Example:

```
print "foo" cmp "bar"; # prints 1
```

Answer (score 5):

`gt` should do the trick

Edit: actually, `cmp` would be more similar to compareTo(), `gt` would just tell you if the string is greater than then the other.

Comment: see `perldoc perlop` for all the details